# How to copy all fields from xml to xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to copy all fields from xml to xslt except the field name="Category"? I use

```
Field[not(name()='Category')]
```

But when I preview the result, it display only the field name="Category" instead of displaying the all field.

XML:

```
<Form name="Form1" type="TextView" label="Cash Pickup Form">

<Field name="Category" type="TextView" label="FormType" value="Form1"/>

<Field type="Delimiter"/>
<Field name="ContractNumber" type="TextView" label="Contract number" value=""/>
<Field type="Delimiter"/>
<Field name="ClientName" type="TextView" label="Name of Client" value=""/>
<Field name="BirthDate" type="TextView" label="Birthday" value=""/>
<Field name="DueDate" type="TextView" label="Due Date" value=""/>
</Form>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="Category" select="/Form/Field[@name='Category']/@value"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Form"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Form">
<xsl:element name="Form">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='ns2') and not(name()='')]"/>
  <xsl:call-template  name="Arrange"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Arrange">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[not(name()='Category')]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the deal with the namespace?

Comment: @michael.hor257k im using namespace for uri

Comment: No idea what you mean, or what that part in your stylesheet does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the expression:

```
Field[not(name()='Category')]
```

selects every Field, because a `Field` element's name is 'Field' - and therefore it cannot be 'Category'. You probably meant:

```
Field[not(@name='Category')]
```

that is a `Field` element that does not have a `name` attribute with a value of 'Category'.

Next, you are applying templates to `Field` - but you have no template matching `Field`, so nothing is applied. If you change the `Arrange` template to:

```
<xsl:template name="Arrange">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[not(@name='Category')]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and add:

```
<xsl:template match="Field">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

you will likely get the result you want.

Of course, you could shorten all that to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Form">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@name | @type | @label | Field[not(@name='Category')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[@name='Category']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will copy everything as is, except the Category field/s.